# Return multiple tags from Phoenix view

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am using Phoenix and want to create a function inside a view which renders some HTML tags and can be called from a template. Let's say I have something like:

```
  def create_my_tags() do
    Tag.content_tag(:span, "1st span", class: "tag is-danger is-small")
    Tag.content_tag(:span, "2nd span", class: "tag is-danger is-small")
  end
```

[image]

This returns only the second span and only this is rendered. How can I trigger side effects for both calls inside? I understand the function returns only last value but is it possible to show both spans?

Comment: Would not returning a list `[tag1, tag2, ...]` help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Aleksei Matiushkin](http://Aleksei%20Matiushkin) suggested in the comment, returning list of tags solves the problem.

```
def create_my_tags() do
  [
    Tag.content_tag(:span, "1st span", class: "tag is-danger is-small"),
    Tag.content_tag(:span, "2nd span", class: "tag is-danger is-small")
  ]  
end
```

Comment: `def create_my_tags(titles), do: Enum.map(titles, &Tag.content_tag(:span, &1, class: "tag is-danger is-small"))` and call it like `create_my_tags(["1st span", "2nd span"])` :)